# how to retrieve data with \n directly in java?

Tags: java

suppose I enter `katheline\njoseph` in a column(datatype- CLOB) of db table.

At the java end , I want the o/p as :

```
katheline

Joseph
```

i.e \n should be recognized as a newline character at the java end.

Is there any ONE single method in java to retrieve db column with \n as newline character.

I don’t want to do any manipulations.. for eg. Usage of string Tokenizer  class or  replace method is not desirable. They work fine but I am looking for a Direct method

Comment: doesnt the \n automatically make it a new line? Or do you want to add 2 new lines for every one \n?

Comment: Where do you want to output this string (in jsp, console, ...)?

Comment: sql doesnot recognize \n as newline character. While retreiving it on java end the string will be retrieved as katheline\njoseph only. i am looking for some direct method

Comment: @user1677123: I think you're approaching it the wrong way: instead of transforming the data *after* you read them, you should write the correct value (i.e. a real newline instead of the two characters `\` and `n`) into the value in the first place.

Comment: i am suppose to get the desired output. Changes in db is not desired

Comment: So the database has wrong input and you're supposed to produce correct output ... great! What about `\t`, `\b`, `\r` and all the other escapes?

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is just a way you can write the char number 10 ("newline") in a string. If you retrieve that char from DB it will be in your string. You can iterate over the chars and verify it is:

```
for(int i=0; i<value.length(); i++)
{
   char c = value.charAt(i);
   int code = value.codePointAt(i);
   System.out.println(c + " - " + code);
}
```

It shound print:

```
A - 65
B - 66

 - 10
C - 67
```

for:

```
AB
C
```

**Manual SQL**

In SQL: try `char(10)` or something similar. It depends on the RDBMS.

**Replacing in Java**

If you can't convert the values in DB to real newlines then you can do:

```
value.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\\n");
```

It receives a regex: `\\n` meaning bar and n
And a replacement: `\n`

As I'm writing a Java string I must escape bars, so that's why so many bars are used.

**Writing values with newline to DB**

Never write values as literal SQL:

```
insert into .... values ('myvalue');
```

Use params:

```
insert into... values (?)
```

and

```
preparedStatement.setParam(1, myValue);
```